# How to execute a target in MSBuild after project references have been built?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Say I have a project depending on another:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ...>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="p1.csproj">
      <Project>{456a45c3-764a-4a7c-8ad4-d83d61cc89bb}</Project>
      <Name>P1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RunAfterBuildingProjRefs" AfterTargets="???">
    ...
  </Target>
</Project>
```

To ensure that target `RunAfterBuildingProjRefs` is executed after all project references (`p1`) are built, what target should I specify in its `AfterTargets` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AfterResolveReferences` as a hook target to run after all references have been resolved. This also includes COM and native references - if you really want project references only, then hooking after `ResolveProjectReferences` is also an option.

See [The ProjectReference Protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/ProjectReference-Protocol.md) for details about how project-to-project references work and which targets are involved.